# Unrecognized Marker Style when using a function for markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out why this piece of my code won't work. I'm trying to set "mark" as a variable so that it can use different markers depending on what a certain column reads. Everything else in the plot works fine, but when I add this part:

```
mark = ["s" if t == "M" else "o" for t in z]

plt.scatter(x2[yesGEM],y1[yesGEM],c="green",label='Observed (GemN)', marker=mark)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Unrecognized marker style ['o', 's', 'o', 'o', 'o', 's', 'o', 'o',......'o']
```

Any idea why this is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490817/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-markers-and-colors

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set `marker` as an iterable when you call `scatter` (see [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)), so you'd have to split your data into two groups and scatter them separately: e.g. (assuming `x2` and `y1` correspond to the values in `z`):

```
data_s = []
data_o = []
for i,t in enumerate(z):
    if t == 'M':
         data_s.append(x2[i], y1[i])
    else:
         data_o.append(x2[i], y1[i])

plt.scatter(*zip(*data_s), marker='s', c='g')
plt.scatter(*zip(*data_o), marker='o', c='g')
```